# Replace all the backticks with tildas by using GUI

Tags: gvim, substitute

To replace

````
```
code blocks fenced with backticks
```
````

with

```
~~~
code blocks fenced with tildas
~~~
```

I can use ```` :%s/```/\~\~\~/g ```` and this works.

However, when I try to replace them with GUI (Edit > Find and Replace), neither `\~\~\~`, nor `~~~` in the "Replace with" field works for me.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug. Tilde and ampersand are special for `:h sub-replace` and "ReplaceAll" handler in `src/gui.c:gui_do_findrepl()` does incorrect escaping.

I've raised [the issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11064).

Upd. Fixed in 9.0.0396.

Comment: Dang. Mine is 9.0.0389. If I'd only waited a few days. :)